# Using custom VirtualPathProvider to load embedded views that inherit a custom WebViewPage

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, virtualpathprovider

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7746253/using-custom-virtualpathprovider-to-load-embedded-resource-partial-views) I am using a custom VirtualPathProvider to retrieve views that are embedded in dlls.  If I don't put `@inherits System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage` on my view I get this error:

```
The view at '~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml' must derive from ViewPage, ViewPage<TModel>, ViewUserControl, or ViewUserControl<TModel>.
```

I'm using a custom BaseViewPage that inherits from WebViewPage.  Before I started using this custom VirtualPathProvider, setting the new base page in the web.config worked.  Now, if I try to inherit my custom class on the page with `@inherits My.BaseViewPage` I get the same error as above.

For completeness' sake I'll add that the page does start to compile if I inherit from WebViewPage, but it throws an error because there is code expecting the view to have properties from BaseViewPage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that the problem had to do with the view engine I was using.  To get the VirtualPathProvider working I replaced the view engine with a custom one that added view locations I needed.  I accidentally inherited from `WebFormsViewEngine` instead of `RazorViewEngine` which is why the error I kept getting was for `ViewPage` instead of `WebViewPage`.  Now that that's all sorted out my custom base view page works just fine.

Comment: ah - so glad I found this answer! :)

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm...is it possible the base class it's failing to resolve properly from your dll?

If that is the case, what you need to do is add a custom assembly/type resolver handler on...(going from memory) AppDomain.AssemblyResolve - in that handler, you'll want to grab the appropriate type from your dll and return that back.

Purely a guess, unfortunately - on my phone, so research capabilities are limited.

Comment: Thanks for answering.  I almost went down this route, but the [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11057293/216553) turned out to be a simple instance of PEBKAC.