# Storing Partial Views outside of the application root

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I am wondering if there is a way to store partial views outside of the application's root folder.  The advantage being that all applications would be able to use these partials, and there would be a single location to make HTML updates without re-deploying a new .bin to each app.

```
@Html.Partial("../../../../../../../../PartialTest/PartialTest.cshtml")
```

This is giving me the error:

> *Cannot use a leading .. to exit above the top directory.*

Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 1):

> I am wondering if there is a way to store partial views outside of the
>   application's root folder.

You will have to write a custom virtual path provider if you want to support that. For example you may take a look at the [`following question`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7746253/using-custom-virtualpathprovider-to-load-embedded-resource-partial-views) for an example of such a custom provider reading views from embedded resources. You could adapt it to read views from whatever location you want.